# Trouble moving a Batch file to an other drive

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, copying

I have tried frequently to move a batch file to the A: drive, it always says , "the syntax of the command is incorrect". Please this error is really getting on my nerves. P.S. this is the command I have been entering:

```
move C:\Users\long (fixed)\Desktop\wow\DOS.bat A:\
```

Comment: I guess you need quotes like this: move "C:\Users\long (fixed)\Desktop\wow\DOS.bat" A:\ since the path contains blanks

Answer (score 1):

```
move "C:\Users\long (fixed)\Desktop\wow\DOS.bat" "A:\"
```

?

without quotes it will take `C:\Users\long` and `(fixed)\Desktop\wow\DOS.bat` for separate arguments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Zulu - the answer to the problem is to put the path in quotes, which is what this answer does.